# Type annotation to state with setup store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I set up a pinia store in `setup store` syntax (see https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Setup-Stores). I use for my whole project typescript but there is no description in pinia for working with typescript and setup stores (instead of option stores).

But there is an issue with type annotation for state variables

```
export const useComponentsStore = defineStore('components', () => {
  ..
  const selectedComponents: ServerConfigComponent[] = ref([]);
  ..
```

The error message is

```
Type 'Ref<never[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'ServerConfigComponent[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 35 more.ts(2740)
```

It works for computed (getters) variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refs are typed using generic parameters  :

```js
const selectedComponents = ref<ServerConfigComponent[]>([]);
```